# How to compare two strings in C# where the beginning part of one is the end of the other

Tags: c#, string, compare

I have two strings, e.g.:

```
str1 = "CGGCAGTGGTAGTCTGAG" 
str2 = "TGAGCGCGCGCGCGCGCG"
```

I want to get the two strings same part "TGAG"

Comment: Did you try something? How would you do it with pencil and paper?

Comment: sure, i can use substring and loop, but if the same parts length is too long, it's low efficiency

Comment: So the parts of the strings at the start and end need to be compared and can be different lengths?

Please confirm the actual issue.

Oh are you looking for the indexes of the parts which match?

Comment: yes , the str1 and str2 have deferent lengths in fact, the same parts also have defrent lengths

Comment: So you have an additional requirement about efficiency,. It would be useful to provide some typical figures (length of the strings, length of the match).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes?

```
public static string GetMatchPart(string str1, string str2, int maxMatchSize)
{
    string tmp = string.Empty;
    for (int i = maxMatchSize; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        tmp = str2.Substring(0, i);
        if (str1.StartsWith(tmp) || str1.EndsWith(tmp))
        {
            return tmp;
        }
        tmp = str2.Substring(str2.Length-i, i);
        if (str1.StartsWith(tmp) || str1.EndsWith(tmp))
        {
            return tmp;
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str1 = "CGGCAGTGGTAGTCTGAG";
    string str2 = "TGAGCGCGCGCGCGCGCG";
    string result = GetMatchPart(str1, str2, 4);
}
```

The result string contains "TGAG", it looks for the largest part that the other string starts or ends with. And returns an empty string if there is no match.

EDIT: I added a maxMatchSize parameter to address your speed issues. With the example strings you provided setting it to 4 results are instant. I thought about using `str1.Length/2` as well.

Comment: very good! this is a method,  but if the same parts length is too long, it's low efficiency

Comment: What is the largest size of the matching part? If I knew that then I can make it much faster.

Comment: I changed my answer to allow you to select a maxMatchSize to address your speed issues. Without further details I cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you!

```
using System;
 

class string_comparison_equals
 
{
    static void Main()
 
    {
        string str1 = "CGGCAGTGGTAGTCTGAG"; 
        string str2 = "TGAGCGCGCGCGCGCGCG";

 
        if (String.Equals(str1[-1:-4], str2[0:3])) or (String.Equals(str1[0:3], str2[-1:-4]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The strings have the same beginning and end");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The strings are different");
        }
 
        Console.ReadLine();
 
    }
 
}
```

> The result should be:
>
> `The strings have the same beginning and end`

Comment: thank you very much,but the same part is deferent in deferent strings ,str1 and str2 is ony my simple  example. the same part length is uncertain in fact